# connect AWS managed Grafana to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, grafana

Hi Stackoverfow users,

I have a question about the connection between AWS managed Grafana and querying an AWS Aurora database (RDS).

I've added a Mysql datasource and added the credentials of my reader instance of the RDS database cluster. This cluster publicly accessibl, but has a security group with an ip whitelist. On testing the connection, the datasource is giving a timeout.

I can't figure out how to add a exception to the whitelist so Grafana has access to the database. I've tried adding the ip-address of Grafana (I pinged the url) to the database whitelist, but that didn't work.

Does anybody know a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Haven't tried it out myself but I suspect you'd need to enable IAM authn and attach the respective policy to the AMG workspace IAM role (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html). BTW, do you have a `AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess` policy on the AMG workspace IAM role?